# Passenger + Apache "TraceEnable Off"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, httpd.conf, phusion

We're using Passenger 4.0.59 behind Apache 2.2 (CentOS 6.latest) with Rails 3.2.

In /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf we have:

```
TraceEnable off
```

We have one virtual host configured in httpd.conf and a second virtual host configured in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf that's configured with Passenger.

I'm using commands of this form to test:

```
curl -I -X {method} https://{host}/{resource}
```

...and seeing the following behavior:

1. When I TRACE a static image over http, i.e. http://host.domain.com/images/foo.png, I get a 405 response (as expected).
2. When I TRACE the same static image over https, meaning it goes through the virtual host configured with Passenger, I get 405 (as expected).
3. However, when I TRACE a Rails service in our app, e.g. https://host.domain.com/status.json, I get a 200 response w/ valid data.

I would expect Apache to shut down the request and return a 405 response before it even gets to Passenger/Rails, but that isn't happening.

What am I missing / misunderstanding?

Comment: After reading [this thread](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=543577#30), can you grep all your Apache config under `/etc/apache` to ensure that there is NO other `TraceEnable` option that would set it to `on`? E.g. in `security.conf`? If not, can you post more relevant parts of your http config, including both of your virtual servers?

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing / misunderstanding?

`TraceEnable off` is the correct directive to use, but you may have another [`TraceEnable`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#traceenable) directive ***elsewhere in your configs***.

You should check all of your apache config files to be sure there is no other [`TraceEnable`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#traceenable) directives.

Since the [`TraceEnable`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#traceenable) directive can be used within either the server config or the virtual host config, so you may just want to add it to both.